# Adding an html element to the jquery code of colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, object, colorbox

I would like to add an element to jquery.colorbox.js(want to do some fancey styling)
But i don't quit understand the way the jquery works

Link to colorbox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Current output example:

```
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: block; opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer;">
</div>

<div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: block; padding-bottom: 42px; padding-right: 42px; top: 0px; left: 456px; position: absolute; width: 871px; height: 646px;">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 688px; width: 913px;">
...
</div>
</div>
```

Desired output example:

```
    <div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: block; opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer;">
    </div>

<div id="colorbox_totalWrapper">
    <div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: block; padding-bottom: 42px; padding-right: 42px; top: 0px; left: 456px; position: absolute; width: 871px; height: 646px;">
    <div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 688px; width: 913px;">
    ...
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current JQuery:

```
defaults = {
    transition: "elastic",
    speed: 300,
    width: false,
    initialWidth: "600",
    innerWidth: false,
    maxWidth: false,
    height: false,
    initialHeight: "450",
    innerHeight: false,
    maxHeight: false,
    scalePhotos: true,
    scrolling: true,
    inline: false,
    html: false,
    iframe: false,
    fastIframe: true,
    photo: false,
    href: false,
    title: false,
    rel: false,
    opacity: 0.9,
    preloading: true,

    current: "image {current} of {total}",
    previous: "previous",
    next: "next",
    close: "close",
    xhrError: "This content failed to load.",
    imgError: "This image failed to load.",

    open: false,
    returnFocus: true,
    reposition: true,
    loop: true,
    slideshow: false,
    slideshowAuto: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 2500,
    slideshowStart: "start slideshow",
    slideshowStop: "stop slideshow",
    onOpen: false,
    onLoad: false,
    onComplete: false,
    onCleanup: false,
    onClosed: false,
    overlayClose: true,     
    escKey: true,
    arrowKey: true,
    top: false,
    bottom: false,
    left: false,
    right: false,
    fixed: false,
    data: undefined
},

colorbox = 'colorbox',
prefix = 'cbox',
boxElement = prefix + 'Element',

// Events   
event_open = prefix + '_open',
event_load = prefix + '_load',
event_complete = prefix + '_complete',
event_cleanup = prefix + '_cleanup',
event_closed = prefix + '_closed',
event_purge = prefix + '_purge',

// Special Handling for IE
isIE = !$.support.opacity && !$.support.style, // IE7 & IE8
isIE6 = isIE && !window.XMLHttpRequest, // IE6
event_ie6 = prefix + '_IE6',

// Cached jQuery Object Variables
$overlay,
$box,
$wrap,
$content,
$topBorder,
$leftBorder,
$rightBorder,
$bottomBorder,
$related,
$window,
$loaded,
$loadingBay,
$loadingOverlay,
$title,
$current,
$slideshow,
$next,
$prev,
$close,
$groupControls,

settings,
interfaceHeight,
interfaceWidth,
loadedHeight,
loadedWidth,
element,
index,
photo,
open,
active,
closing,
loadingTimer,
publicMethod,
div = "div",
init;


// Convience function for creating new jQuery objects
function $tag(tag, id, css) {
    var element = document.createElement(tag);

    if (id) {
        element.id = prefix + id;
    }

    if (css) {
        element.style.cssText = css;
    }

    return $(element);
}

// Determine the next and previous members in a group.
function getIndex(increment) {
    var 
    max = $related.length, 
    newIndex = (index + increment) % max;

    return (newIndex < 0) ? max + newIndex : newIndex;
}

// Convert '%' and 'px' values to integers
function setSize(size, dimension) {
    return Math.round((/%/.test(size) ? ((dimension === 'x' ? $window.width() : $window.height()) / 100) : 1) * parseInt(size, 10));
}
```

this regex.
    function isImage(url) {
        return settings.photo || /.(gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|ico)((#|\?).*)?$/i.test(url);
    }

```
// Assigns function results to their respective properties
function makeSettings() {
    var i,
        data = $.data(element, colorbox);

    if (data == null) {
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults);
        if (console && console.log) {
            console.log('Error: cboxElement missing settings object')
        }
    } else {
        settings = $.extend({}, data);          
    }

    for (i in settings) {
        if ($.isFunction(settings[i]) && i.slice(0, 2) !== 'on') { // checks to make sure the function isn't one of the callbacks, they will be handled at the appropriate time.
            settings[i] = settings[i].call(element);
        }
    }

    settings.rel = settings.rel || element.rel || 'nofollow';
    settings.href = settings.href || $(element).attr('href');
    settings.title = settings.title || element.title;

    if (typeof settings.href === "string") {
        settings.href = $.trim(settings.href);
    }
}

function trigger(event, callback) {
    $.event.trigger(event);
    if (callback) {
        callback.call(element);
    }
}

// Slideshow functionality
function slideshow() {
    var
    timeOut,
    className = prefix + "Slideshow_",
    click = "click." + prefix,
    start,
    stop,
    clear;

    if (settings.slideshow && $related[1]) {
        start = function () {
            $slideshow
                .text(settings.slideshowStop)
                .unbind(click)
                .bind(event_complete, function () {
                    if (settings.loop || $related[index + 1]) {
                        timeOut = setTimeout(publicMethod.next, settings.slideshowSpeed);
                    }
                })
                .bind(event_load, function () {
                    clearTimeout(timeOut);
                })
                .one(click + ' ' + event_cleanup, stop);
            $box.removeClass(className + "off").addClass(className + "on");
            timeOut = setTimeout(publicMethod.next, settings.slideshowSpeed);
        };

        stop = function () {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            $slideshow
                .text(settings.slideshowStart)
                .unbind([event_complete, event_load, event_cleanup, click].join(' '))
                .one(click, function () {
                    publicMethod.next();
                    start();
                });
            $box.removeClass(className + "on").addClass(className + "off");
        };

        if (settings.slideshowAuto) {
            start();
        } else {
            stop();
        }
    } else {
        $box.removeClass(className + "off " + className + "on");
    }
}

function launch(target) {
    if (!closing) {

        element = target;

        makeSettings();

        $related = $(element);

        index = 0;

        if (settings.rel !== 'nofollow') {
            $related = $('.' + boxElement).filter(function () {
                var data = $.data(this, colorbox), 
                    relRelated;

                if (data) {
                    relRelated =  data.rel || this.rel;
                }

                return (relRelated === settings.rel);
            });
            index = $related.index(element);

            // Check direct calls to ColorBox.
            if (index === -1) {
                $related = $related.add(element);
                index = $related.length - 1;
            }
        }

        if (!open) {
            open = active = true; // Prevents the page-change action from queuing up if the visitor holds down the left or right keys.

            $box.show();

            if (settings.returnFocus) {
                $(element).blur().one(event_closed, function () {
                    $(this).focus();
                });
            }

            // +settings.opacity avoids a problem in IE when using non-zero-prefixed-string-values, like '.5'
            $overlay.css({"opacity": +settings.opacity, "cursor": settings.overlayClose ? "pointer" : "auto"}).show();

            // Opens inital empty ColorBox prior to content being loaded.
            settings.w = setSize(settings.initialWidth, 'x');
            settings.h = setSize(settings.initialHeight, 'y');
            publicMethod.position();

            if (isIE6) {
                $window.bind('resize.' + event_ie6 + ' scroll.' + event_ie6, function () {
                    $overlay.css({width: $window.width(), height: $window.height(), top: $window.scrollTop(), left: $window.scrollLeft()});
                }).trigger('resize.' + event_ie6);
            }

            trigger(event_open, settings.onOpen);

            $groupControls.add($title).hide();

            $close.html(settings.close).show();
        }

        publicMethod.load(true);
    }
}

// ColorBox's markup needs to be added to the DOM prior to being called
// so that the browser will go ahead and load the CSS background images.
function appendHTML() {
    if (!$box && document.body) {
        init = false;

        $window = $(window);
        $box = $tag(div).attr({id: colorbox, 'class': isIE ? prefix + (isIE6 ? 'IE6' : 'IE') : ''}).hide();
        $overlay = $tag(div, "Overlay", isIE6 ? 'position:absolute' : '').hide();
        $wrap = $tag(div, "Wrapper");
        $content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
            $loaded = $tag(div, "LoadedContent", 'width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden'),
            $loadingOverlay = $tag(div, "LoadingOverlay").add($tag(div, "LoadingGraphic")),
            $title = $tag(div, "Title"),
            $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
            $next = $tag(div, "Next"),
            $prev = $tag(div, "Previous"),
            $slideshow = $tag(div, "Slideshow").bind(event_open, slideshow),
            $close = $tag(div, "Close")
        );

        $wrap.append( // The 3x3 Grid that makes up ColorBox
            $tag(div).append(
                $tag(div, "TopLeft"),
                $topBorder = $tag(div, "TopCenter"),
                $tag(div, "TopRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $leftBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleLeft"),
                $content,
                $rightBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $tag(div, "BottomLeft"),
                $bottomBorder = $tag(div, "BottomCenter"),
                $tag(div, "BottomRight")
            )
        ).find('div div').css({'float': 'left'});

        $loadingBay = $tag(div, false, 'position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none');

        $groupControls = $next.add($prev).add($current).add($slideshow);

        $(document.body).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
    }
}

// Add ColorBox's event bindings
function addBindings() {
    if ($box) {
        if (!init) {
            init = true;

            // Cache values needed for size calculations
            interfaceHeight = $topBorder.height() + $bottomBorder.height() + $content.outerHeight(true) - $content.height();//Subtraction needed for IE6
            interfaceWidth = $leftBorder.width() + $rightBorder.width() + $content.outerWidth(true) - $content.width();
            loadedHeight = $loaded.outerHeight(true);
            loadedWidth = $loaded.outerWidth(true);

            // Setting padding to remove the need to do size conversions during the animation step.
            $box.css({"padding-bottom": interfaceHeight, "padding-right": interfaceWidth});

            // Anonymous functions here keep the public method from being cached, thereby allowing them to be redefined on the fly.
            $next.click(function () {
                publicMethod.next();
            });
            $prev.click(function () {
                publicMethod.prev();
            });
            $close.click(function () {
                publicMethod.close();
            });
            $overlay.click(function () {
                if (settings.overlayClose) {
                    publicMethod.close();
                }
            });

            // Key Bindings
            $(document).bind('keydown.' + prefix, function (e) {
                var key = e.keyCode;
                if (open && settings.escKey && key === 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    publicMethod.close();
                }
                if (open && settings.arrowKey && $related[1]) {
                    if (key === 37) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $prev.click();
                    } else if (key === 39) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $next.click();
                    }
                }
            });

            $('.' + boxElement, document).live('click', function (e) {
                // ignore non-left-mouse-clicks and clicks modified with ctrl / command, shift, or alt.
                // See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/click-events/
                if (!(e.which > 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    launch(this);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Don't do anything if ColorBox already exists.
if ($.colorbox) {
    return;
}

// Append the HTML when the DOM loads
$(appendHTML);


// ****************
// PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
// Usage format: $.fn.colorbox.close();
// Usage from within an iframe: parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
// ****************

publicMethod = $.fn[colorbox] = $[colorbox] = function (options, callback) {
    var $this = this;

    options = options || {};

    appendHTML();

    if (addBindings()) {
        if (!$this[0]) {
            if ($this.selector) { // if a selector was given and it didn't match any elements, go ahead and exit.
                return $this;
            }
            // if no selector was given (ie. $.colorbox()), create a temporary element to work with
            $this = $('<a/>');
            options.open = true; // assume an immediate open
        }

        if (callback) {
            options.onComplete = callback;
        }

        $this.each(function () {
            $.data(this, colorbox, $.extend({}, $.data(this, colorbox) || defaults, options));
        }).addClass(boxElement);

        if (($.isFunction(options.open) && options.open.call($this)) || options.open) {
            launch($this[0]);
        }
    }

    return $this;
};

publicMethod.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
    var 
    top = 0, 
    left = 0, 
    offset = $box.offset(),
    scrollTop, 
    scrollLeft;

    $window.unbind('resize.' + prefix);

    // remove the modal so that it doesn't influence the document width/height        
    $box.css({top: -9e4, left: -9e4});

    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft();

    if (settings.fixed && !isIE6) {
        offset.top -= scrollTop;
        offset.left -= scrollLeft;
        $box.css({position: 'fixed'});
    } else {
        top = scrollTop;
        left = scrollLeft;
        $box.css({position: 'absolute'});
    }

    // keeps the top and left positions within the browser's viewport.
    if (settings.right !== false) {
        left += Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth - setSize(settings.right, 'x'), 0);
    } else if (settings.left !== false) {
        left += setSize(settings.left, 'x');
    } else {
        left += Math.round(Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0) / 2);
    }

    if (settings.bottom !== false) {
        top += Math.max($window.height() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight - setSize(settings.bottom, 'y'), 0);
    } else if (settings.top !== false) {
        top += setSize(settings.top, 'y');
    } else {
        top += Math.round(Math.max($window.height() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0) / 2);
    }

    $box.css({top: offset.top, left: offset.left});

    // setting the speed to 0 to reduce the delay between same-sized content.
    speed = ($box.width() === settings.w + loadedWidth && $box.height() === settings.h + loadedHeight) ? 0 : speed || 0;

    // this gives the wrapper plenty of breathing room so it's floated contents can move around smoothly,
    // but it has to be shrank down around the size of div#colorbox when it's done.  If not,
    // it can invoke an obscure IE bug when using iframes.
    $wrap[0].style.width = $wrap[0].style.height = "9999px";

    function modalDimensions(that) {
        $topBorder[0].style.width = $bottomBorder[0].style.width = $content[0].style.width = that.style.width;
        $content[0].style.height = $leftBorder[0].style.height = $rightBorder[0].style.height = that.style.height;
    }

    $box.dequeue().animate({width: settings.w + loadedWidth, height: settings.h + loadedHeight, top: top, left: left}, {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            modalDimensions(this);

            active = false;

            // shrink the wrapper down to exactly the size of colorbox to avoid a bug in IE's iframe implementation.
            $wrap[0].style.width = (settings.w + loadedWidth + interfaceWidth) + "px";
            $wrap[0].style.height = (settings.h + loadedHeight + interfaceHeight) + "px";

            if (settings.reposition) {
                setTimeout(function () {  // small delay before binding onresize due to an IE8 bug.
                    $window.bind('resize.' + prefix, publicMethod.position);
                }, 1);
            }

            if (loadedCallback) {
                loadedCallback();
            }
        },
        step: function () {
            modalDimensions(this);
        }
    });
};

publicMethod.resize = function (options) {
    if (open) {
        options = options || {};

        if (options.width) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.width, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
        }
        if (options.innerWidth) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.innerWidth, 'x');
        }
        $loaded.css({width: settings.w});

        if (options.height) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.height, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
        }
        if (options.innerHeight) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.innerHeight, 'y');
        }
        if (!options.innerHeight && !options.height) {
            $loaded.css({height: "auto"});
            settings.h = $loaded.height();
        }
        $loaded.css({height: settings.h});

        publicMethod.position(settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed);
    }
};

publicMethod.prep = function (object) {
    if (!open) {
        return;
    }

    var callback, speed = settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed;

    $loaded.remove();
    $loaded = $tag(div, 'LoadedContent').append(object);

    function getWidth() {
        settings.w = settings.w || $loaded.width();
        settings.w = settings.mw && settings.mw < settings.w ? settings.mw : settings.w;
        return settings.w;
    }
    function getHeight() {
        settings.h = settings.h || $loaded.height();
        settings.h = settings.mh && settings.mh < settings.h ? settings.mh : settings.h;
        return settings.h;
    }

    $loaded.hide()
    .appendTo($loadingBay.show())// content has to be appended to the DOM for accurate size calculations.
    .css({width: getWidth(), overflow: settings.scrolling ? 'auto' : 'hidden'})
    .css({height: getHeight()})// sets the height independently from the width in case the new width influences the value of height.
    .prependTo($content);

    $loadingBay.hide();

    // floating the IMG removes the bottom line-height and fixed a problem where IE miscalculates the width of the parent element as 100% of the document width.
    //$(photo).css({'float': 'none', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'});

    $(photo).css({'float': 'none'});

    // Hides SELECT elements in IE6 because they would otherwise sit on top of the overlay.
    if (isIE6) {
        $('select').not($box.find('select')).filter(function () {
            return this.style.visibility !== 'hidden';
        }).css({'visibility': 'hidden'}).one(event_cleanup, function () {
            this.style.visibility = 'inherit';
        });
    }

    callback = function () {
        var preload, 
            i, 
            total = $related.length, 
            iframe, 
            frameBorder = 'frameBorder', 
            allowTransparency = 'allowTransparency', 
            complete, 
            src, 
            img, 
            data;

        if (!open) {
            return;
        }

        function removeFilter() {
            if (isIE) {
                $box[0].style.removeAttribute('filter');
            }
        }

        complete = function () {
            clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
            $loadingOverlay.hide();
            trigger(event_complete, settings.onComplete);
        };

        if (isIE) {
            //This fadeIn helps the bicubic resampling to kick-in.
            if (photo) {
                $loaded.fadeIn(100);
            }
        }

        $title.html(settings.title).add($loaded).show();

        if (total > 1) { // handle grouping
            if (typeof settings.current === "string") {
                $current.html(settings.current.replace('{current}', index + 1).replace('{total}', total)).show();
            }

            $next[(settings.loop || index < total - 1) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.next);
            $prev[(settings.loop || index) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.previous);

            if (settings.slideshow) {
                $slideshow.show();
            }

            // Preloads images within a rel group
            if (settings.preloading) {
                preload = [
                    getIndex(-1),
                    getIndex(1)
                ];
                while (i = $related[preload.pop()]) {
                    data = $.data(i, colorbox);

                    if (data && data.href) {
                        src = data.href;
                        if ($.isFunction(src)) {
                            src = src.call(i);
                        }
                    } else {
                        src = i.href;
                    }

                    if (isImage(src)) {
                        img = new Image();
                        img.src = src;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $groupControls.hide();
        }

        if (settings.iframe) {
            iframe = $tag('iframe')[0];

            if (frameBorder in iframe) {
                iframe[frameBorder] = 0;
            }
            if (allowTransparency in iframe) {
                iframe[allowTransparency] = "true";
            }
            // give the iframe a unique name to prevent caching
            iframe.name = prefix + (+new Date());
            if (settings.fastIframe) {
                complete();
            } else {
                $(iframe).one('load', complete);
            }
            iframe.src = settings.href;
            if (!settings.scrolling) {
                iframe.scrolling = "no";
            }
            $(iframe).addClass(prefix + 'Iframe').appendTo($loaded).one(event_purge, function () {
                iframe.src = "//about:blank";
            });
        } else {
            complete();
        }

        if (settings.transition === 'fade') {
            $box.fadeTo(speed, 1, removeFilter);
        } else {
            removeFilter();
        }
    };

    if (settings.transition === 'fade') {
        $box.fadeTo(speed, 0, function () {
            publicMethod.position(0, callback);
        });
    } else {
        publicMethod.position(speed, callback);
    }
};

publicMethod.load = function (launched) {
    var href, setResize, prep = publicMethod.prep;

    active = true;

    photo = false;

    element = $related[index];

    if (!launched) {
        makeSettings();
    }

    trigger(event_purge);

    trigger(event_load, settings.onLoad);

    settings.h = settings.height ?
            setSize(settings.height, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight :
            settings.innerHeight && setSize(settings.innerHeight, 'y');

    settings.w = settings.width ?
            setSize(settings.width, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth :
            settings.innerWidth && setSize(settings.innerWidth, 'x');

    // Sets the minimum dimensions for use in image scaling
    settings.mw = settings.w;
    settings.mh = settings.h;

    // Re-evaluate the minimum width and height based on maxWidth and maxHeight values.
    // If the width or height exceed the maxWidth or maxHeight, use the maximum values instead.
    if (settings.maxWidth) {
        settings.mw = setSize(settings.maxWidth, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
        settings.mw = settings.w && settings.w < settings.mw ? settings.w : settings.mw;
    }
    if (settings.maxHeight) {
        settings.mh = setSize(settings.maxHeight, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
        settings.mh = settings.h && settings.h < settings.mh ? settings.h : settings.mh;
    }

    href = settings.href;

    loadingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $loadingOverlay.show();
    }, 100);

    if (settings.inline) {
        // Inserts an empty placeholder where inline content is being pulled from.
        // An event is bound to put inline content back when ColorBox closes or loads new content.
        $tag(div).hide().insertBefore($(href)[0]).one(event_purge, function () {
            $(this).replaceWith($loaded.children());
        });
        prep($(href));
    } else if (settings.iframe) {
        // IFrame element won't be added to the DOM until it is ready to be displayed,
        // to avoid problems with DOM-ready JS that might be trying to run in that iframe.
        prep(" ");
    } else if (settings.html) {
        prep(settings.html);
    } else if (isImage(href)) {
        $(photo = new Image())
        .addClass(prefix + 'Photo')
        .error(function () {
            settings.title = false;
            prep($tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.imgError));
        })
        .load(function () {
            var percent;
            photo.onload = null; //stops animated gifs from firing the onload repeatedly.

            if (settings.scalePhotos) {
                setResize = function () {
                    photo.height -= photo.height * percent;
                    photo.width -= photo.width * percent;   
                };
                if (settings.mw && photo.width > settings.mw) {
                    percent = (photo.width - settings.mw) / photo.width;
                    setResize();
                }
                if (settings.mh && photo.height > settings.mh) {
                    percent = (photo.height - settings.mh) / photo.height;
                    setResize();
                }
            }

            if (settings.h) {
                photo.style.marginTop = Math.max(settings.h - photo.height, 0) / 2 + 'px';
            }

            if ($related[1] && (settings.loop || $related[index + 1])) {
                photo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                photo.onclick = function () {
                    publicMethod.next();
                };
            }

            if (isIE) {
                photo.style.msInterpolationMode = 'bicubic';
            }

            setTimeout(function () { // A pause because Chrome will sometimes report a 0 by 0 size otherwise.
                prep(photo);
            }, 1);
        });

        setTimeout(function () { // A pause because Opera 10.6+ will sometimes not run the onload function otherwise.
            photo.src = href;
        }, 1);
    } else if (href) {
        $loadingBay.load(href, settings.data, function (data, status, xhr) {
            prep(status === 'error' ? $tag(div, 'Error').html(settings.xhrError) : $(this).contents());
        });
    }
};

// Navigates to the next page/image in a set.
publicMethod.next = function () {
    if (!active && $related[1] && (settings.loop || $related[index + 1])) {
        index = getIndex(1);
        publicMethod.load();
    }
};

publicMethod.prev = function () {
    if (!active && $related[1] && (settings.loop || index)) {
        index = getIndex(-1);
        publicMethod.load();
    }
};

// Note: to use this within an iframe use the following format: parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
publicMethod.close = function () {
    if (open && !closing) {

        closing = true;

        open = false;

        trigger(event_cleanup, settings.onCleanup);

        $window.unbind('.' + prefix + ' .' + event_ie6);

        $overlay.fadeTo(200, 0);

        $box.stop().fadeTo(300, 0, function () {

            $box.add($overlay).css({'opacity': 1, cursor: 'auto'}).hide();

            trigger(event_purge);

            $loaded.remove();

            setTimeout(function () {
                closing = false;
                trigger(event_closed, settings.onClosed);
            }, 1);
        });
    }
};

// Removes changes ColorBox made to the document, but does not remove the plugin
// from jQuery.
publicMethod.remove = function () {
    $([]).add($box).add($overlay).remove();
    $box = null;
    $('.' + boxElement)
        .removeData(colorbox)
        .removeClass(boxElement)
        .die();
};

// A method for fetching the current element ColorBox is referencing.
// returns a jQuery object.
publicMethod.element = function () {
    return $(element);
}

;

    publicMethod.settings = defaults;

}(jQuery, document, this));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to be like you need to use a callback from the colorbox to get this working.

Here is an example.

```
$.colorbox({
  open: true,
  height: 500,
  width: 500,
  onComplete: function() {
      $("#colorbox").wrap("<div id='colorbox_totalWrapper' />")
  },
  onCleanup: function() {
      $("#colorbox").unwrap("<div id='colorbox_totalWrapper' />")
  }
});
```

From Joy's comment below.

- Here is a jsfiddle that shows this working - http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7U6Rn/

**References**

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: This works, you may add this fiddle in your answer, http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7U6Rn/, You can prove by inspecting the code.